# Authenticate using Google javascript API

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to use the Gmail API to access the email in a web application. I have tried the example at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php and is working fine. Now I want to get the access token using javascript API and use in the above example.

```
gapi.auth2.authorize({
  client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scope: 'email profile openid',
  response_type: 'id_token permission'
}, function(response) {
  if (response.error) {
    // An error happened!
    return;
  }
  // The user authorized the application for the scopes requested.
  var accessToken = response.access_token;
  var idToken = response.id_token;
  // You can also now use gapi.client to perform authenticated requests.
});
```

When I manually add the response from javascript API in the php script it is showing error

```
Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken' in D:\wamp\www\gmailexample\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\src\Google\Client.php:267
```

Below is the php script I am using.

```
<?php
require_once '/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

  $accessToken= json_decode('{"access_token":"asdfsasdfsasdfsasdfs","expires_in":2255,"expires_at":254877}', true);
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
  print "No labels found.\n";
} else {
  print "Labels:\n";
  foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
    printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please show what is your php script?

Comment: @Morfinismo    I have updated the question with php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my friend, here is your solution. To make sure you understand this, I worked an example. First, inside your working directory, make sure you have the Google PHP Client library and two other files. The first one should be called **index.php** and paste the following code inside that file:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <title>JS/PHP Google Sample</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function handleClientLoad() {
        // Loads the client library and the auth2 library together for efficiency.
        // Loading the auth2 library is optional here since `gapi.client.init` function will load
        // it if not already loaded. Loading it upfront can save one network request.
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      function initClient() {
        // Initialize the client with API key and People API, and initialize OAuth with an
        // OAuth 2.0 client ID and scopes (space delimited string) to request access.
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: 'YOUR API KEY GOES HERE',
            clientId: 'YOUR CLIENT ID GOES HERE',
            scope: 'email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        });
      }

      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        // When signin status changes, this function is called.
        // If the signin status is changed to signedIn, we make an API call.
        if (isSignedIn) {
            $("#signout-button").show();
            $("#signin-button").hide();
            makeApiCall();
        } else {
            $("#signin-button").show();
            $("#signout-button").hide();
        }
      }

      function handleSignInClick(event) {
        // Ideally the button should only show up after gapi.client.init finishes, so that this
        // handler won't be called before OAuth is initialized.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      function handleSignOutClick(event) {
        var host = "http://"+window.location.hostname;
        gapi.auth2.GoogleUser.prototype.disconnect();
        window.open(host, "_self");
      }

      function makeApiCall() {
        // Make an API call to the People API, and print the user's given name.       
        var accsTkn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().$K.Q7.access_token;    
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("access_token", accsTkn); //send access token

        $.ajax({
            url : 'listEmails.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success : function(html) {

                $("#myLabels").append(html);

            }
        });

      }

    </script>

    <style>

        #signin-button{
            display: none;
        }

        #signout-button{
            display: none;
        }

        #myLabels{
            width: 80%;
            min-height: 350px;
        }

    </style>


  </head>

  <body>

    <center>

        <h1>Google OAuth Gmail Example with Javascript and PHP</h1><br>

        <button id="signin-button" onclick="handleSignInClick()">Sign In</button>

        <br><br><br>

        <div id="myLabels">
            Emails list: <br><br>

        </div>      

        <br><br>
        <button id="signout-button" onclick="handleSignOutClick()">Sign Out</button>

    </center>


    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Next, the second file should be named **listEmails.php** and paste the following code inside:

```
<?php session_start();     

require_once "path_to_php_client_lib/vendor/autoload.php"; //include php client library

//set the required parameteres
$scopes = array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");

$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'listEmails.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);

$client->setAccessToken($_POST["access_token"]);
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client); // define service to be rquested

$pageToken = NULL;
$messages = array();
$opt_param = array("maxResults" => 5);

try {
  $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages("me", $opt_param);
  if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
    $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

foreach ($messages as $message) {
    $msgId = $message->getId();
    $optParams = array("format" => "full");
    $uniqueMsg = $service->users_messages->get("me", $msgId, $optParams);
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $uniqueMsg->id . '<br>';
    print 'Message From: ' . $uniqueMsg->getPayload()->getHeaders()[18]->value . '<br><br>**************************<br><br>';
}


?>
```

**Understanding the example:**
The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) clearly explains

> This OAuth 2.0 flow is called the implicit grant flow. It is designed for applications that access APIs only while the user is present at the application. These applications are not able to store confidential information.

That means that using the Javascript authentication flow you will NOT be able to get offline access. Having that in mind, we can move on.

As you can then see on the php script, you are not required to refresh the token since this will be managed by the Javascript client library; And there you go... I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. You saved the day.

Comment: But still javascript API is not providing the refresh token. So  PHP script is throwing the same error after one hour when the token is expired.

Comment: I tried with the example here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow. But when I paste the code I am getting as response into the php script $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode); is giving responseArray
(
    [error] => unauthorized_client
    [error_description] => Unauthorized
)

Comment: @user1690835 There you go my friend. A pleasure to help you!

Comment: But what I want is to send the authorization code once to the server and server will save the access token with refresh token. I found why refresh token was not there in the response. It is because refresh token will be sent only in the very first request. After that, if you want the refresh token in your response then you have to remove the application from your account.

Comment: @user1690835 in that case Don't use JavaScript. Use only PHP.

Comment: I am using JavaScript and everything is working fine.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you did this. I have the same scenerio. I am authorizing user from javascript end and sending auth code to server side. but php is returning empty object with that auth code.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR I suggest you to post a new question, put your complete code and explain in details what you are doing, what you are getting and what you are expecting. Then I will be glad to take a look.